# How do I raycast from a sphere to an ui element in the canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, virtual-reality, raycasting

I would like to Raycast from the center of Sphere GameObject to find the text/image element being hit by the ray. I'm using Physics.RaycastAll to detect the UI element being hit. Following is my code.

```
public class RaycastUI : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Sphere;

    private Vector3 _origin;
    private Vector3 _direction;

    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit[] hits;

        // get the origin and direction
        _origin = Sphere.transform.position;
        _direction = Sphere.transform.forward;

        //raycast all
        hits = Physics.RaycastAll(_origin, _direction, 100.0F);

        // retrieve the names of the element that are hit by the sphere.
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++) {
            RaycastHit hit  = hits[i];
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added BoxCoilloider to the canvas. Unfortunately, `hits.Length` always returns 0. am I missing something? How do I ray cast from the sphere to the ui element in the canvas to check if it has collided?

Comment: You might need to put it over a transparent image that you can use as a raycast target

Comment: do you mean I should put my buttons within the transparent image?

Comment: No, buttons would be fine as they have an image, however, pure text does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use the `EventSystem` if you want to check against UI elements.

Try something like this:

```
private void GetUIObjectsOfPosition(Vector2 screenPosition)
{
    var eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    eventDataCurrentPosition.position = screenPosition;

    var results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);

    foreach (var result in results) {
        Debug.Log(result.gameObject.name);
    }               
}
```

You can calculate the screen position from your spheres world position using [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html).

Comment: It works now but it only detects the panel not the UI elements within the panel :(

Comment: I have got a panel that overlaps the buttons hence it is preventing the buttons from receiving the clicks. is ti possible to bring the buttons forward so that the panel does not hide the button?

Comment: You can try to experiment with the `Raycast Target` property of the components. Also check your `Graphic Raycaster` (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html)